# Remove mobile menu when linking to anchor IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not the biggest JS developer, so its perhaps simple. But I've made a JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4xm3whzf/1/

My issue is that since I'm just linking to titles on the same page the menu doesn't close when a menu-item have been chosen. How can I make sure it scrolls down and the menu go away again?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mobile_menu").simpleMobileMenu({
      onMenuLoad: function(menu) {
        console.log(menu)
        console.log("menu loaded")
      },
      onMenuToggle: function(menu, opened) {
        console.log(opened)
      }
    });
  })



  /**
   * JQuery Simple MobileMenu
   * https://github.com/Position2/jQuery-Simple-MobileMenu
   */
  ! function(s) {
    var e = {
      hamburgerId: "sm_menu_ham",
      wrapperClass: "sm_menu_outer",
      submenuClass: "submenu",
      onMenuLoad: function() {
        return !0
      },
      onMenuToggle: function() {
        return !0
      }
    };
    s.fn.simpleMobileMenu = function(n) {
      if (0 === this.length) return this;
      var t = {},
        a = s(this),
        i = function() {
          t.hamburger = s("<div/>", {
            id: t.settings.hamburgerId,
            html: "<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>"
          }), t.smmOuter = s("<div/>", {
            class: t.settings.wrapperClass
          }), a.appendTo(t.smmOuter), t.hamburger.add(t.smmOuter).appendTo(s("body"))
        },
        u = function() {
          t.smmOuter.find("ul." + t.settings.submenuClass).each(function() {
            var e = s(this),
              n = e.closest("li"),
              t = n.find("> a"),
              a = s("<li/>", {
                class: "back",
                html: "<a href='#'>" + t.text() + "</a>"
              });
            n.addClass("hasChild"), a.prependTo(e)
          })
        };
      t.settings = s.extend({}, e, n), i(), u(), "function" == typeof t.settings.onMenuLoad && t.settings
        .onMenuLoad(a), t.hamburger.click(function(e) {
          s("#" + t.settings.hamburgerId).toggleClass("open"), s("." + t.settings.wrapperClass).toggleClass(
            "active").find("li.active").removeClass("active"), s("body").toggleClass(
            "mmactive"), "function" == typeof t.settings.onMenuToggle && t.settings.onMenuToggle(
            a, s("#" + t.settings.hamburgerId).hasClass("open"))
        }), t.smmOuter.find("li.hasChild > a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(), s("." + t.settings.wrapperClass).scrollTop(0), s(this).parent().addClass(
            "active").siblings().removeClass("active")
        }), t.smmOuter.find("li.back a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(), s(this).closest("ul." + t.settings.submenuClass).parent().removeClass(
            "active")
        })
    }
  }(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: green;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.mobile_menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.sm_menu_outer.active .mobile_menu {
  display: block;
}
.sm_menu_outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -9;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #0a5552 0%, #00a19a 100%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.sm_menu_outer.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}
.mobile_menu {
  padding-top: 7rem;
}
.sm_menu_outer .mobile_menu a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Sub Menu anim */
.sm_menu_outer .mobile_menu .submenu {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #0a5552 0%, #00a19a 100%);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.sm_menu_outer .mobile_menu li.active > .submenu {
  right: 0;
}
.sm_menu_outer .mobile_menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #2a2a2a 20%, #2a2a2a 50%, #2a2a2a 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) 0 0 1 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.sm_menu_outer .mobile_menu li.hasChild > a {
  background: url("../images/next.png") no-repeat scroll 95% center / 5% auto;
}
/*Hamburger Animation */
#sm_menu_ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 30px;
  top: 2.6rem;
  right: 2rem;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#sm_menu_ham span {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 30px;
}
#sm_menu_ham span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}
#sm_menu_ham span:nth-child(2), #sm_menu_ham span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10px;
}
#sm_menu_ham span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 20px;
}
#sm_menu_ham.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 18px;
  width: 0;
}
#sm_menu_ham.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#sm_menu_ham.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#sm_menu_ham.open span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 18px;
  width: 0;
}
/*@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {}
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}
 @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}*/
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #sm_menu_ham, .sm_menu_outer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<nav id="desktop">


  <ul id="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#derfor">Derfor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#features">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#process">Proces</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</nav>



<nav id="mobile">

  <ul class="mobile_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#derfor">Derfor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#features">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#process">Proces</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>








<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="derfor">Derfor</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="features">features</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="process">Proces</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="derfor">Derfor</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add simple event listener which can be triggered when link clicked. You can see an example of code below.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul.mobile_menu > li > a'), b => b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("body.mmactive, div#sm_menu_ham"),
    e => e.className = "")

  document.getElementsByClassName('sm_menu_outer')[0].classList.remove("active");
}, false));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Position2/jQuery-Simple-MobileMenu/master/dist/jquery-simple-mobilemenu.min.js"></script>
<nav id="desktop">


  <ul id="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#derfor">Derfor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#features">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#process">Proces</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</nav>



<nav id="mobile">

  <ul class="mobile_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#derfor">Derfor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#features">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#process">Proces</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>








<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="derfor">Derfor</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="features">features</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="process">Proces</h1>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;padding-top:300px">

  <h1 id="derfor">Derfor</h1>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/yaymer/4xm3whzf/10/)